# MYSQL ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE for copying table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, temporary and permanent table.
My objective is to copy temporary data into permanent table but must update the permanant table.

## Below are the tables

```
### Temp. table
CREATE TABLE `tb_temp_data` (
  `key_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `h00` int(11) DEFAULT '0',  
  `h01` int(11) DEFAULT '0',  
  `h02` int(11) DEFAULT '0',  
  `h03` int(11) DEFAULT '0',  
  `h04` int(11) DEFAULT '0',  
  `h05` int(11) DEFAULT '0',  
  `h06` int(11) DEFAULT '0',  
  `h07` int(11) DEFAULT '0',  
  `h08` int(11) DEFAULT '0',  
  `h09` int(11) DEFAULT '0',  
  `h10` int(11) DEFAULT '0',  
  `h11` int(11) DEFAULT '0',  
  `h12` int(11) DEFAULT '0',  
  `h13` int(11) DEFAULT '0',  
  `h14` int(11) DEFAULT '0',  
  `h15` int(11) DEFAULT '0',  
  `h16` int(11) DEFAULT '0',  
  `h17` int(11) DEFAULT '0',  
  `h18` int(11) DEFAULT '0',  
  `h19` int(11) DEFAULT '0',  
  `h20` int(11) DEFAULT '0',  
  `h21` int(11) DEFAULT '0',  
  `h22` int(11) DEFAULT '0',  
  `h23` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `grand_total` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`key_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

### Permanant table
CREATE TABLE `tb_permanant_data` (
  `key_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',  
  `h00` int(11) DEFAULT '0',  
  `h01` int(11) DEFAULT '0',  
  `h02` int(11) DEFAULT '0',  
  `h03` int(11) DEFAULT '0',  
  `h04` int(11) DEFAULT '0',  
  `h05` int(11) DEFAULT '0',  
  `h06` int(11) DEFAULT '0',  
  `h07` int(11) DEFAULT '0',  
  `h08` int(11) DEFAULT '0',  
  `h09` int(11) DEFAULT '0',  
  `h10` int(11) DEFAULT '0',  
  `h11` int(11) DEFAULT '0',  
  `h12` int(11) DEFAULT '0',  
  `h13` int(11) DEFAULT '0',  
  `h14` int(11) DEFAULT '0',  
  `h15` int(11) DEFAULT '0',  
  `h16` int(11) DEFAULT '0',  
  `h17` int(11) DEFAULT '0',  
  `h18` int(11) DEFAULT '0',  
  `h19` int(11) DEFAULT '0',  
  `h20` int(11) DEFAULT '0',  
  `h21` int(11) DEFAULT '0',  
  `h22` int(11) DEFAULT '0',  
  `h23` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `grand_total` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`key_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

INSERT INTO tb_permanant_data 
       SELECT * FROM  tb_temp_data ;
       ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE h00 = ?
```

I want to make sure all h00 until h23 will be updated by adding the value into tb_permanant_data but i have no idea on how to do that...

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Do these 24 `hxx` fields store different data? Or just data for every hour of the day? If it's the second case, your tables needs normalization.

Comment: Yes to store 24 hours. Have to do this design because too many keys... So how is the sql statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO tb_permanant_data SELECT * FROM tb_temp_data 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
  h00 = VALUES(h00),
  h01 = VALUES(h01),
  h02 = VALUES(h02),
  h03 = VALUES(h03),
  h04 = VALUES(h04),
  h05 = VALUES(h05),
  h06 = VALUES(h06),
  h07 = VALUES(h07),
  h08 = VALUES(h08),
  h09 = VALUES(h09),
  h10 = VALUES(h10),
  h11 = VALUES(h11),
  h12 = VALUES(h12),
  h13 = VALUES(h13),
  h14 = VALUES(h14),
  h15 = VALUES(h15),
  h16 = VALUES(h16),
  h17 = VALUES(h17),
  h18 = VALUES(h18),
  h19 = VALUES(h19),
  h20 = VALUES(h20),
  h21 = VALUES(h21),
  h22 = VALUES(h22),
  h23 = VALUES(h23);
```

Note, table `tb_permanant_data` can contain rows which doesn't exist in `tb_temp_data` (by `id`).